# How to use the keys id and name in the "Users" table?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, key, relational-database

I made the field `Name` the only primary key. This was useful until you needed to rename the user. Now I want to add a `id`. How do we now make the identifiers so that:

1. The uniqueness of the `Name` remains
2. Is there an easy and quick access through the `Name`?

I made the `id` the primary key, the `Name` an alternative. But now I cannot use `db.Users.Find (Name)`

upd
Make that:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(u => u.Name).IsUnique();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query for finding names in stead of Find method
var users= Users.Where(s => s.Name=="yourname").FirstOrDefault();